# How can I easily tag a photo I am previewing?

Tags: photos

I take a lot of photos on my Droid M THEN I have to go through them and select the best ones to upload. I need to preview full-screen to see if it's a good photo but then there is no way to mark/tag/select it in preview mode. You can Select a photo but only in thumbnail view.

Is there a way to select (or, better, tag) a photo in full screen preview mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[F-Stop Media Gallery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fstop.photo) does exactly that. You can preview photos and it has an on-screen 5 star rating and "favorite" button.

Unfortunately, the tags don't "stay" with the photo if you upload to Google+ or Facebook.